# Xamarin.Forms Why is my tap command not working?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this kind of tap command in my carousel view:

```
                                                        <Image
                                                         x:Name="img_adPic" 
                                                         HeightRequest="150"
                                                         Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                         Source="{Binding thumbnail}">
                                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference page}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.CurrentIndex, Source={x:Reference page}}"/>
                                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                                                        </Image>
```

I gave my contentpage a name :

```
<ContentPage x:Name="page" >
```

Now in my class:

```
  public ICommand CarouselItemTapped{ get; set; }


    public Page_MainMenuDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CarouselItemTapped = new Xamarin.Forms.Command((selectItem) =>
        {

        });

        instance = this;

     
    }
```

But no matter what I try, the command is NEVER fired. I think i did everything as in the tutorials, why is this not working?

Thank you

Comment: your path is `BindingContext.TapCommand` but your actual command is named `CarouselItemTapped`

Comment: Can you explain this PATH a little more?

Comment: this is in YOUR code - `Command="{Binding  Path=BindingContext.TapCommand` but there is no command in your model named "TapCommand"

Comment: Can u put this as an answer with the correction in my code? unfortunately i dont understand much about how to set this path and what has to be called TapCommand? :)

Comment: there is not enough context in your post for me to be able to tell you if there are additional problems beyond the one I've already pointed out

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the code below about how to use the `TapCommand`. The command would be triggled when you tap on the image.
Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <CarouselView
            x:Name="carouselView"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            IndicatorView="indicatorview">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image
                        x:Name="img_adPic"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Source="{Binding .}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference page}}"  />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        </CarouselView>
        <IndicatorView
            x:Name="indicatorview"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=" 0.5,0.95,100,100"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags=" PositionProportional"
            IndicatorColor=" LightGray"
            IndicatorSize=" 10"
            SelectedIndicatorColor=" Black" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
  public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ICommand CarouselItemTapped { get; set; }
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var list = new List<string>
        {
            "pink.jpg",
            "pink.jpg",
            "pink.jpg",
            "pink.jpg",
            "pink.jpg",
        };
        carouselView.ItemsSource = list;
        //CarouselItemTapped = new Xamarin.Forms.Command((selectItem) =>
        //{

        //});
        //instance = this;
        TapCommand = new Command(commandEvent);
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public void commandEvent()
    {

    }
}
```